# How to bind all arguments of a event emitter

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, discord.js

Is there a way to pass all `Client.on()` args to a function? (Client extends BaseClient extends EventEmitter) for example:

```js
Client.on("event", args => { function.call(args) })
```

I'm using TypeScript

Comment: Just use `Client.on("event", function)`?

Comment: Do you really mean to use `.call()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

- Use the `...`-operator.

  ```
  Client.on("event", (...args) => {
    fx(...args);
  });
  ```
- Use call or apply:

  ```
  Client.on("event", (...args) => {
    fx.apply(this, args);
  });

  Client.on("event", (...args) => {
    fx.call(this, ...args);
  });
  ```
- Use the function directly:

  ```
  Client.on("event", fx);
  ```